# Kendo UI Grid fires create event on sorting

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid, crud

https://jsfiddle.net/sshetye08/1uh6m6wj/4/

Steps to reproduce.

1. Click on "Add new record".
2. Click on sort icon of any column.
3. Observe the grid data.

Bug : Record getting saved though I haven't clicked "save" icon.

Does anyone have any solution for this.

index.html

```
<base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing">
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div id="grid"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read:  {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    id: "ProductID",
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        sortable: true,
                        navigatable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 550,
                        toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                        columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 120 },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 120 },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: 120 },
                            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 150 }],
                        editable: true
                    });
                });
```

Comment: What do you mean by the record is getting saved?  It is certainly added to the local dataSource(otherwise it wouldn't be in the grid at all) but the dataSource's create transport(which is where you would persist it on the server) is not getting called.  If you refresh the grid, the new row won't be there unless you click Save.

Answer (score 0):

The record isn't being saved, it's only added to the grid. There is in fact a bug that makes the "dirty" annotation (the small red triangle) disappear after you sort but if you click on the "CANCEL CHANGES" button, the added row will be removed while rows that were saved with the "SAVE CHANGES" button will remain.